# How do you structure the tests for your server applications in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

I'm starting to add tests to our Node.js server apps since we are slowly deploying into production. I have an API with many possible requests to test.

My question is: how do you structure your tests so it doesn't become a big file in which you quickly get lost?

I wrote tests for **one** API route (I have many other API routes to test) and this is how it looks (in Sublime file overview) :

[image: code hell]

And this test doesn't even cover all cases yet.

I'm using `mocha`, along with `should` and `expect` for validation, and `superagent` for API calls. How would you structure these tests so it doesn't evolve in a hideous big file?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are lots of ways to break down the files into smaller, more manageable parts. Most of them pivot around the use of the `--recursive` flag in `mocha`. In the end, its a matter of personal choice and what works for the team/individual.

### Option 1: Namespacing via dot notation

Run `mocha` without the `--recursive` flag and name your files using dot notation. You can then break it down further by HTTP method and even further, if you'd like, by pass/fail. For instance, a user route would have a file name like `route.user.get.pass.js` and be in the root of the `test/` folder. The code for this file would look like:

```
describe('GET /users', function () {
  describe('when the request is valid', function () {
    it('should return 200 OK');
    it('should have unicorns');
    it('should have ponies too');
  });
});
```

And then another test with file name `route.resource.post.fail.js` would look like:

```
describe('POST /users', function () {
  describe('when the request is invalid', function () {
    it('should return 400 Bad Request');
    ...
  });
});
```

This makes grepping individuals tests a breeze when using `mocha`'s grep feature

### Option 2: Namespacing via folders

Similar to option 1, however, in this case you would use the `--recursive` flag when running `mocha` and use folders instead of nesting file names.

```
test/
  routes/
    users/
      post.js
      get.js
      put.js
  models/
    User.js
```

### Option 3: Separate using modules

This approach is a combination of the first two and should be run without the `--recursive` flag. In the root of the `test` directory, you would name the spec file as `routes.userSpec.js` with code like:

```
describe('/users', function () {

  describe('GET', function () {

    var tests = require('./users/get');

    it('should return 200 OK', tests.200);
    it('should have unicorns', tests.unicorns);
    it('should have ponies too', tests.ponies);

  });

  describe('POST', function () {

    var tests = require('./users/post');

    it('should return 200 OK', tests.200);
    it('should create unicorns', tests.unicorns);
    it('should create ponies too', tests.ponies);

  });

});
```

And then you would define modules in the `test/users` folder looking something like:

```
test/
  users/
    get.js
    post.js
  routes.userSpec.js
```

### Option 4: Code folding

Sometimes large files are unavoidable and this is why all good text editors have a code folding feature.

Comment: I actually like the third option more. I think it can keep a good index of all tests in one place, while still keeping all the specific stuff in other files.

Very good answer, thank you!

Comment: Thats the option I use too — and for the same reason you mentioned. I like to write my entire spec out first as a way to "pre plan" the project.

Comment: Thank you - option 3 is by far my favorite.. thank you

Comment: This is useful to me too. I prefer the option 3. Thanks